# c code popen error "can not allocate memory" only when running in virtual machine

Tags: c, virtual-machine

I wrote a program using c, which I use popen to open a pipe and execute a command line. 
This program works fine in host, but when I run the program in vbox, ubuntu12.04, error:can not allocate memory displayed.

My code is:

```
FILE *fp;
char path[100];
  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen(pdpcall, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening pipe pdpcall: %s\n",strerror(errno));
      pclose(fp);
    exit(0);
  }
  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    if(strncmp(decision,path,strlen(decision))==0)
    {
        pclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
```

I also try a test program only have popen in VM, it works fine. But can not work within my program.

I guess the reason is that in my program, I use a lot of malloc, and might not free. The memory in Vbox is smaller than host, so there are memories errors.
But I change the vbox memory from 512m to 2G, it still the same errors.
Is there any other problems within VM. How to solve this problems.

Comment: I have been told that memory in a Virtual Machine is by default, initialized to empty on boot, whereas in a regular box it is likely that there is some unclean stuff left behind.  Moral: calloc / initialize your memory properly

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks When you exec the OS is going to zero the entire process space before loading the new image to prevent the new executable from scanning the old one's memory. If he is running into problems with non-zeroed memory it is memory that he wrote to and then freed.

Comment: Did you try running it with valgrind on your host? Might reveal problems that only manifest themselves in the VM for some reason.

Comment: nitpick : `pclose` in the first test block is not necessary, since you got an error on opening.

Comment: @lethal-guitar If he is running into a memory leak on the VM, shouldn't he run valgrind there? If he was able to increase the VM memory and still get the error, there might be no memory leak at all on the physical machine if the compiler did some sort of optimization to remove the offending allocation (like if it is unnecessary).

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would warrant a memory error in a VM. You should give a minimal, complete compilable program exposing the issue.

Comment: @user2482551 I assumed he used the same binary on both VM and host. Hadn't considered that he would compile on the VM..